# Sketch the level curves (contour lines) of the function?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$ f(x,y)=e^{x^2+y^2}-1. $$

My attempt:

Let $$e^{(x^2+ y^2)} - 1 = C$$
$$\Leftrightarrow e^{(x^2+ y^2)} = C+1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^2+ y^2 = log(C+1)$$

This equation represents a circle with radius $\sqrt{log(C+1)}$

But I don't quite know how to use this knowledge to sketch the level curves of f.

Comment: I think people here already forgotten when initiated in Calculus and had doubts, consider such questions as silly and qualify negative, I do not like. I'm giving a upvote to counteract

Comment: You already has solved the problem, you have proved that all contour lines are circunferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, this equation represents a circle with radius $\sqrt{\ln\left(C+1\right)}$. Plots of these curves for select $C$ (for example, plots of concentric circles with radius $\sqrt{\ln\left(C+1\right)}$ for $C=0,1,2,3$) are the plots of the level curves.